Go command stdout to multiple writers
In Go, I want to execute a command and capture the results to be processed. However, the command is paginated and should continue receiving input from the user (ie: page through results). I'm only either able to capture results OR paginate but not both.
Here is a sample to showing this...
func main() {
  filename := "./test.txt"
  r, w, err := os.Pipe()
  if err != nil {
    panic("You probably want to fail more gracefully than this")
  }
  defer w.Close()

  stdout := os.Stdout
  os.Stdout = w
  var buf bytes.Buffer

  cmd := exec.Command("less", filename)
  cmd.Stdin = r
  cmd.Stdout = io.MultiWriter(stdout, &buf)
  //cmd.Stdout = stdout
  cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

  log.Print("------STARTING COMMAND------")
  if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Command execution error:", err)
  }
    
  os.Stdout = stdout
  log.Print("------------------------------------")
  log.Print("------FINISHED COMMAND------")
  log.Print("------------------------------------")
  log.Print(buf.String())
}

The above code will capture the results and output correctly, however it does not allow you to page through the content.
If I comment out cmd.Stdout = io.MultiWriter(stdout, &buf) and add back in cmd.Stdout = stdout, it will allow you to page through results but will not capture output. Not sure how to accomplish both.
To get the command to page through results, it looks like cmd Stdin and Stdout need to be os.file pointers. Anything else (ie: MultiWriter or TeeReader) does not behave as expected.

why do that? Just disable pager and page the output yourself if you want. Normally programs that automatically runs a pager to pipe its output (systemctl, man, git...) will detect if its stdout is a pipe and disable pager in that case. But a pager and any other sane programs will to the same, unless an option like --color=always or --pager=always is used

"You probably want to fail more gracefully than this" it's so much easier - but also far more useful - to panic(err).  Then you'll get some useful information about the error, not some silly string.

Thanks for the feedback. @erik258, this isn't the actual code but sample illustrating the issue.

@phuclv I believe you're right and this might not be doable the way we're trying. We're looking into using a pseudo-terminal to help with this like https://github.com/creack/pty.
